# Lifetime of structure's object is shorter than lifetime of structure's member

Tags: rust

I have some trouble to correctly understand lifetime concept in Rust. Especially in reference to structure's object itself and structure's member.
Following minimal example is showing an issue I struggle with:

```
use redis::{Connection, PubSub};

pub struct Db<'a> {
    conn: Connection,
    pubsub: Option<PubSub<'a>>
}

impl<'a> Db<'a> {
    fn open(address: &str) -> Self {
        let client = redis::Client::open(address).unwrap();
        let conn = client.get_connection().unwrap();
        Self {conn, pubsub: None}
    }

    fn subscribe(&'a mut self) {
        let pubsub = self.conn.as_pubsub();
        self.pubsub = Some(pubsub)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut db = Db::open("localhost");
    db.subscribe();
}
```

Compilation ends with following error:

```
error[E0597]: `db` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:22:5
   |
22 |     db.subscribe();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
23 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `db` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `db` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Db<'_>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

I need `pubsub` variable as structure's member and `PubSub` type has a field which is reference to `redis::Connection`. Therefore, lifetime must be defined for this structure explicitly.

As far as I understand, in `subscribe` function I'm defining that object itself must live at least for an `a` lifetime as well. However, compilation error informs me that when `db` is dropped it is still borrowed by `pubsub` reference. Isn't dropping `db` means dropping the reference as it is structure's member?

What should I do to fix this error? My goal is to still have `pubsub` as structure's member and `subscribe` function which utilizes `self.conn`. I have tried with another lifetime `b` defined for `self`, but didn't achieve anything and code still didn't compile.

Comment: Self-referencial data structures are very compilicated in general and a nightmare for the borrow checker. It will probably involve `unsafe` blocks and the `Pin` trait.
The problem is that the `db` object might get moved, which would invalidate the reference. Therefore some magic with `Pin` has to be involved. Sadly, that's also beyond my knowledge of Rust.

Comment: I think an easier solution to your problem is to find a program structure that doesn't require storing the `Connection` and the `PubSub` object in the same data structure.

Answer (score 5):

This is a tricky problem with destructors, specifically the so-called "Drop Check". The error message refers to this as

```rust
borrow might be used here, when `db` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Db<'_>`
```

You can read all the details about the Drop Check [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dropck.html), and you'll see that you essentially replicated the example given in the article.

The problem starts with the fact that `PubSub` has a destructor (an `impl Drop for PubSub`). Your  `Db` type has an implicit destructor created for it, which calls the destructor on the `PubSub`- and the `Connection`-member when `Db` is destroyed. However, when the `PubSub`-destructor executes, it supposedly has access to things of lifetime of `'a` (because it is a `fn drop(&'a mut self)`, where `'a` comes from `PubSub<'a>`, which comes from `Db<'a>`) and could **potentially** observe things of lifetime `'a` that were already destroyed when the destructor for `Db<'a>` began its work. That is because the destructor of `Db<'a>` might have destroyed other members before it tried to destroy `PubSub`, and the compiler can't rule out that the `PubSub`-destructor could reach back into the partially destroyed `Db`.

The reasoning makes perfect sense: A `PubSub` is just a thin wrapper around `&mut Connection`. If this `&mut Connection` refers to the `Connection` in `Db` (which it does!), and the destructor for `Db` first destroyed `Connection` and then destroys `PubSub`, the destructor of `PubSub` accesses an already-destroyed `Connection` through the `&mut Connection`. The compiler chooses the safe route of rejecting the program.

The article mentioned above shows ways out of this. You could implement your own `unsafe` destructor for `Db<'a>`, which needs to "promise" to always destroy `pubsub` before it destroys `conn`. However, since `PubSub` is really only an thin layer around `&mut Connection`, its probably easiest to remove the `pubsub` member from `Db<'a>` and create it whenever required - its a zero-cost operation anyway.

Comment: I was quite confused by the example given in the nomicon when I read about the drop check chapter a few days ago: when it talks abouts this example, it says that changing the order of declaration of these fields won't help (and yes, it won't), but literally at the same page, it says that fields in the struct are dropped in same order of their declaration. I am still confused to this day, am I missing something?

Comment: @TinusgragLin, RFC1857 can't fully solve the problem. While the drop order of tuples and structs without explicit `Drop` impls is defined in-order, there is nothing stopping you from implementing `Drop` for a struct yourself and messing with that order; in addition (as stated in the nomicon), `Vec` is an example where the compiler can only "see" a pointer, but the library code "knows" that there are values behind that pointer and how to drop those, and in which order.  In the general case, solving the Drop-order would mean solving the Halteproblem, and the compiler can't do that

Comment: Thanks for your demystification! Now it starts to make sense to me.